# Variation swatches are loaded 2 times

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am making a webshop, but having some trouble with the variables on a product page.
[Example page can be seen here][1]

I have installed the plugin [WooCommerce Variation Swatches](https://getwooplugins.com/plugins/woocommerce-variation-swatches/?utm_source=wp-admin-plugins&utm_medium=go-pro&utm_campaign=woo-variation-swatches&utm_term=woodmart). On the product page I choose that the variables should be shown as buttons. But when the page loads, the page is first showing the normal WooCommerce variables and also the Variation Swatches from the plugin.

After 1 sec the 2 are merged together(see on the example page). Is it not possible to make only the swatches load?

I tried to change the site to another server, I tried to use a plugin to change the order of loading js and css, but that did not help anything.

Does anybody have a suggestion how I can solve this?

Best regards

Comment: I also use woodmart on two of my sites. It is very slow and bulky imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your website is not very good optimized, it is taking a lot of time to finish loading all extra CSS and assets from all the plugins, including the **WooCommerce Variation Swatches** one.

And thus the CSS from the plugin that hides the native WooCommerce Swatches takes about 0.5 to 2 sec to kick in, that's why the web page makes a repaint and shows the two 'Swatches bars'.

Easy solution, add this on top of the main CSS file or as an inline style. `<style></style>` in your **theme** header.php file **before** a line that has `wp_head();` function call:

```css
.woo-variation-swatches-theme-child-woodmart .woo-variation-items-wrapper>.swatches-select, 
.woo-variation-swatches-theme-woodmart .woo-variation-items-wrapper>.swatches-select {
  display: none;
}
```

Better and clean solution, devote sometime to improve your WordPress performance, try to use as few plugins as possible as many of them are badly coded, follow Google Page Speed advices **[here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.onlinerelation.dk%2Fprodukt%2Fdouglas-terrassebraedder%2F&tab=desktop)** and also I recommend that you check and make sure you're using PHP 7+ in case you're not already.